# TypeScript: exclude "null" and "undefined" from a value of type

Tags: typescript

Support there is some value:

```
let value: string | null;
```

then somewhere along the way I'm certain that it's never null. But there is a function that expects a non-nullable type:

```
function my_func(arg: string){}
```

How do I tell TypeScript that my value is alright for it?

```
my_func(value);
// Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type 'string'
```

Comment: I know it's a noob question and it has an answer elsewhere, but that question is not google-friendly for people looking to solve a specific problem. This one is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `!`:

```
my_func(value!);
```